# Automatically Download Latest WhatsApp APK using Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I'm trying to create a cron job that downloads the latest version of WhatsApp's APK from their website using a bash script and make it available through my site.

So far, I'm able to obtain the version number from the site using the following (user-agent part omitted):

```
wget -q -O - "$@" whatsapp.com/android | grep -oP '(?<=Version )([\d.]+)'
```

And I can download the APK using the following command:

```
wget http://www.whatsapp.com/android/current/WhatsApp.apk
```

That part is fine. What I can't figure out is how to download the APK only if it's newer than the existing APK on the server. How should the script be?

Since I'm not a command-line pro, I guess there's a better way to achieve this than my current approach, so if you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to manage the version yourself.
I would store the apk files with a version number in the filename, e.g  `WhatsApp_<version-number>_.apk`. So the script that downloads the newer file can be as following:

```
# Get the local version
oldVer=$(ls -v1 | grep -v latest | tail -n 1 | awk -F "_" '{print $2}')
# Get the server version
newVer=$(wget -q -O - "$@" whatsapp.com/android | grep -oP '(?<=Version )([\d.]+)')
# Check if the server version is newer
newestVer=$(echo -e "$oldVer\n$newVer" | sort -n | tail -n 1)
#Download the newer versino
[ "$newVer" = "$newestVer" ] && [ "$oldVer" != "$newVer" ]  && wget -O WhatsApp_${newVer}_.apk http://www.whatsapp.com/android/current/WhatsApp.apk || echo "The newest version already downloaded"
#Delete all files that not is a new version
find  ! -name "*$newVer*"  ! -type d  -exec rm -f {} \;
# set the link to the latest
ln -sf $(ls -v1 | grep -v latest| tail -n1) latest
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make the latest version available using a static URL, something like: example.com/latest.apk. I don't want to store all the APKs in my server. Is it possible to accomplish that? (Thanks for answering, by the way!)

Comment: I've changed a little the answer, now the `latest` should be a soft link that points to the latest downloaded `apk`. I hope this will help you